# Custom mime type for directories

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop, xdg

Is it possible to make a custom mime type for directories (inode/directory)?
Just like what MacOS does with *.app folders (app bundle) which make it possible to open them in another program.

Comment: Do you mean associating MIME types, *in a browser*, with directories?

Comment: @Greenonline I mean like when you create a mime type xml which is installed with xdg-mime. Is it possible to make a mime type like this but for directories?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but see [MIME type for a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18869772/4424636) and see [`man xdg-mime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime) and maybe try to experiment with that. I think that answer will depend upon the OS used..

Comment: Did you find anything new so far?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what specific problem you're trying to solve. If you had the answer to your question, what would you be able to do that you can't do now?

Comment: @WGRM, no, I didn't do anything about it because I had other things to do. I don't even know where to file the issue so I've just gave up long time ago since it was just curiosity and no one will ever distribute .app with mach-o and elf binaries along. [ravynOS](https://airyx.org/) does so with a customized file manager.

Comment: @MDeBusk, just out of curiosity. It could be even convenient to assing some folders to open directly into some software. This would make possible to use MacOS app bundles (.app) folders into other unix systems (no that it is necessary, but why not?).

Comment: I want to use appimages that way. I already extracted such applications and renamed it to `progname.app`. If the mime type was recognized, i could associate the default application and make it a script that starts the corresponding program beneath. Maybe appimages will add a link like `application` so it can be found easily. And there you go, a use case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. At least it won't work.

I have tried it several times and it does NOT work, while file associations work without any hassle. Here is some example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/x-macos-app">
    <sub-class-of type="inode/directory"/>
    <glob-deleteall/>
    <glob pattern="*.app" case-sensitive="false" weight="100"/>
    <comment>macOS Application</comment>
    <treemagic>
        <treematch path="path/to/Test.app" type="directory" match-case="false" />
    </treemagic>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

> This must be placed in `${HOME}/.data/mime/packages`. Update via `update-mime-database "${XDG_DATA_HOME}/mime/"`

I'm pretty certain, that this is a bug, noone noted or cares about. So you may file it, to draw attention. Please report back, if you get other results.

It actually should work, as shown by this example, which makes sense:

```
<mime-type type="x-content/image-dcf">
  <comment>digital photos</comment>
  <treemagic>
    <treematch path="dcim" type="directory" non-empty="true"/>
  </treemagic>
</mime-type>
```

[Source](https://github.com/freedesktop/xdg-shared-mime-info/blob/master/data/freedesktop.org.xml.in) [Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#idm45802172165792)

Addendum

I tried with path="Test.app", again. But it didn't work either. It is described, that it looks within the mounted root. I tried both, with and without sub-folders.